# How to re-render UI in response to computed property buried in a nested class?

Tags: swiftui, combine

It's not clear to me how you would combine the output of the following computed property, to the UI.

```
var isComplete: Bool {
    Set([.givenName, .familyName]).isSubset(of: elements)
}
```

I essentially want the user interface to update if the above changes. How would I do this using Combine?

Reactive programming demands that I now think backwards and I'm having trouble thinking about model <<< UI rather than model >>> UI.

Here is the code in context.

```
struct EditPersonView: View {
    
    let model: ViewModel
            
    private var captionView: some View {
        HStack {
        /*
          stuff
        */
            if submitted && model.name.isComplete {
                Spacer()
                Text("select".localizedCapitalized) + Text(" ") + Text("save") + Text(" ") + Text("")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
    /*
    stuff - including captionView
    */
    }
}

extension EditPersonView {
    
    final class ViewModel {
        
        let name: PersonName
        
        init(person: Person) {
            self.name = PersonName(for: person)
        }
    }
}

extension EditPersonView.ViewModel {
    
    final class PersonName {
        
        let person: Person
        
        private let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
        
        init(for person: Person) {
            self.person = person
        }
        
        var text: String {
            get { person.name ?? "" }
            set { person.name = newValue }
        }
        
        private var components: PersonNameComponents? {
            formatter.personNameComponents(from: text)
        }
        
        var givenName: String? {
            components?.givenName
        }
        
        var familyName: String? {
            components?.familyName
        }
        
        private func isValid(component: String?) -> Bool {
            if let name = component, name.count > 1 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        
        var elements: Set<Elements> {
            var collection = Set<Elements>()
            if isValid(component: givenName) { collection.insert(.givenName) }
            if isValid(component: familyName) { collection.insert(.familyName) }
            return collection
        }
        
        var isComplete: Bool {
            Set([.givenName, .familyName]).isSubset(of: elements)
        }
    }
}

extension EditPersonView.ViewModel.PersonName {
    
    enum Elements {
        case givenName, familyName
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use ObservableObject as class and @Published var isComplete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I came up with.

The root of the sequence is the `textPublisher`.  This begins the sequence with the values sent to `text`.

`didSet` sends the text to the sequence and saves it in the person's name just as the original code does.

`isComplete` becomes a publisher that sends `true` or `false` depending on whether the components are valid.  The chain of `map` operators each take the value through one step of the computations in your original code.  You could easily reduce this to a single `map` I would think. (or filter the computations out into functions with meaningful names and substitute the functions for the closures)

An external `Subscriber` could subscribe to `isComplete` and respond when it emits a `true` value.

```
final class PersonName {
    var person: Person

    private let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()

    let textPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    var text: String {
        get { person.name ?? "" }
        set { textPublisher.send(newValue); person.name = newValue }
    }

    var isComplete : AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>!

    init(for person: Person) {
        self.person = person

        isComplete = textPublisher
            .map{ self.formatter.personNameComponents(from: $0) }
            .map{ (components: PersonNameComponents?) -> Set<Elements> in
                var collection = Set<Elements>()

                if let components = components {
                    if self.isValid(component: components.givenName) { collection.insert(.givenName) }
                    if self.isValid(component: components.familyName) { collection.insert(.familyName) }
                }

                return collection
            }
            .map { Set([Elements.givenName, Elements.familyName]).isSubset(of: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private func isValid(component: String?) -> Bool {
        if let name = component, name.count > 1 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```